# Heartbeat not working. Port not opened

Tags: serial-port, heartbeat

I have been trying to place two virtual machine with heartbeat. osboxes and osboxes2.

When I run `nmap localhost` this is the output:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00017s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
443/tcp   open  https
631/tcp   open  ipp
3306/tcp  open  mysql
9050/tcp  open  tor-socks
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
```

Here is the tcpdump of such interface `eth0`:

```
18:38:22.267817 IP 192.168.141.135.48748 > 192.168.141.255.694: UDP, length 315
18:38:22.268640 IP 192.168.141.135.38234 > osboxes2.694: UDP, length 315
18:38:22.269421 IP osboxes2 > 192.168.141.135: ICMP osboxes2 udp port 694 unreachable, length 351
```

As you can see `udp port 694 unreachable`. When i try to ping `osboxes` from `osboxes2`:

```
PING 192.168.141.137 (192.168.141.137) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.141.137: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.284 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.141.137: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.291 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.141.137: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.681 ms
```

`ha.cf` file from `osboxes`:

```
#Arquivo de log de debug:
logfile /var/log/ha-log

#Arquivo de log
debugfile /var/log/ha-debug

#Para onde vai os logs
logfacility local0

#Frequencia em segundo de batimentos cardicados
keepalive 2

#Tempo indica a morte do node
deadtime 25

#Tempo que o heartbeat deve esperar por beats (nao o beat dos beatboxes)
warntime 10

#Tempo maximo para declarar o outro servidor morto
initdead 50

#Porto de sincronia
udpport 694

#Endereco de broadcast da rede
bcast eth0

#Nao entendi. Se for preciso vai la procurar depois.
ucast eth0 192.168.141.137

#Determinar se o servidor volta para o master caso ele responda
auto_failback on

#Nome dos nodes do cluster
node osboxes2
node osboxes
```

`haresourcers` from `osboxes`:

```
osboxes 192.168.141.135 apache
```

It's worth noting that `osboxes`(principal node) is `192.168.141.135` and `osboxes2` is `192.168.141.137`.

I guessing the problem resides in the `port 694 not opened` since it is `unreachable`.

Comment: Do you get any error message when you try to start the heartbeat process?

Comment: No. Everything is running smothly besides the `port unreachable`. I had to delete `hb_regeneration` from the `/var/lib/heartbeat` because of some error that I can't remember of.

Comment: I'm looking at `syslog` and I saw this: `Dec 22 18:48:42 osboxes heartbeat: [8933]: info: glib: UDP Broadcast heartbeat started on port 694 (694) interface eth0
Dec 22 18:48:42 osboxes heartbeat: [8933]: info: glib: UDP Broadcast heartbeat closed on port 694 interface eth0 - Status: 1
`. I don't know if it's relevant to the question.

Comment: No `iptables` rules active?

Comment: @wurtel there is no IP tables rules up.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `bcast` line from your configuration (or just commenting it out).

By defining `ucast` and `bcast` you're essentially telling heartbeat to use two different communication types (unicast and broadcast), which might be confusing things.

The linux-ha.org wiki has some documentation regarding all the possible directives for the heartbeat config: http://linux-ha.org/wiki/Ha.cf

Most of that information can also be found in the man page as well: `# man ha.cf`

Comment: something strange just happened. I fired up the virtual machine and `tcpdump -i eth0` and there wasn't any `port unreachable` anymore. After 5 minutes with the machine up i start to get `port unreachable` again. I commented out the `bcast` line as you advised me to, unfortunately with no lucky.

Comment: I have changed the port to 80 at `udpport` and it works fine for now. I wonder if there is any problem with changing the port to an `http`. Any security reasons or any other reason?